# How to install gatsby?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

When I try to install gatsby running npm install gatsby-cli -g , it shows that is successfuly installed but it does not work  when I run gatsby --help oder gatsby -- build .... , it shows:

```
-bash: gatsby: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

the reason you are getting that is that you haven't installed it globally

- `$ npm i -g gatsby`
- `$ source ~/.bashrc`

`source` will refresh your terminal so you don't need to close it and open it up again

cli commands only work with globally installed packages

Answer (score 0):

The Gatsby CLI is available via npm and should be installed globally by running:

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

If you are unable to successfully run the Gatsby CLI due to a permissions issue, you may want to check out the npm docs on [fixing permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

Answer (score 0):

global flag -g comes first while installing any package

instead of `npm install gatsby-cli -g` run `npm i -g gatsby-cli`

---

**any of below will work**

`npm install --global <package_name_to_install>`

`npm install -g <package_name_to_install>`

`npm i --global <package_name_to_install>`

`npm i -g <package_name_to_install>`

---

for you **package_name_to_install** is ***gatsby-cli***